# Computing solutions to the quadratic equation in bash

Tags: bash

Thanks for taking the time to read the question, so basically I have some issue with my homework on how to calculate a trinomial solution. I know there are other tutorials on the site but I want to show you what I have come up with and guide me through my issues. I have tried altering some code or changes here and there but not much

```
#!/bin/bash
read a
read b
read c

d=$((b*b-4*a*c))

if ((d>=0)); then
    calc=$(echo "sqrt ($d)" | bc )
    x1=$((-b/2*a+calc/2*a))
    x2=$((-b/2*a-calc/2*a))
    echo "$x1""$x2"
else
    echo "To trionimo den exei pragmatikes rizes"
fi
```

After I try any set of numbers it would just show me errors in different lines.

Comment: You should not make use of bash to do any computation. Bash is not a computing language. Bash also does not handle floating point arithmetic so you would need a different language for this. You could consider writing everything in `bc` using the flag `-l` or better, consider the use of python.

Comment: Don't read parameters.  Instead of `read a; read b; read c;`, do `a=$1; b=$2; c=$3` and pass the values when you call the script.

Comment: What error are you getting? How do you execute your script and how do you input the three values? I've tried [reproducing your problem](https://ideone.com/SvBxNJ) but I didn't reach any error

Comment: i know i highly prefer python for calculations, but a homework is a homework :/ and homework says bash

Comment: well  when i imput 1 5 2 i get the errors :main.sh: line 5: 5
: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
")
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
main.sh: line 8: 5
: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
"

Comment: Do you put the 3 integers on the same line, or do you press enter after each one? As your script is written, you need to do the second one (each `read` reads a whole line). No problem with 1 5 2 for me , it gives the output 0-4. Executed as `./script.sh<enter>1<enter>5<enter>2<enter>`

Comment: so is my machine faulty? if it works fine for you that might be the case..

Comment: If you need to do it in bash, write a `HEREDOC` which contains a python script which you pipe to python.

Comment: @kvantour OP is working on bash homework, I doubt using python is a solution there

Comment: @FilipposPapalos can you include the way you're calling the script? I think this is more likely to be the problem there

Comment: wrt `homework says bash` - `bc` is an external command and so is no more `bash` than `awk` or `python` or any other external command. So what is the homework really about? Do you have to only use bash builtins (i.e. not `bc`) or only standard UNIX tools called from bash (e.g. `bc` or `awk`) or any UNIX tools (e.g. `python` or `perl`) or something else?

Comment: @Aaron what do you mean by that friend?

Comment: Are you testing the script by running it in a shell yourself? If so I'd like you to add in your question how you do so, since there are a few ways which could lead to a problem.

Comment: i have used many online emulators and have gotten those errors @Aaron

Comment: Please don't blindly apply tags like "linux", even if that tag is suggested by Stack Overflow. Read the description and make an informed decision instead. BASH in particular is not Linux-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a homework question. So I will not provide you with a fully written out solution, I will give you information and point you in the correct direction.

---

**general note:** when you finished writing a script, Copy-paste it into http://www.shellcheck.net and check for possible problems. If shellcheck reports any, follow the suggested links on that page and read the information on how to solve the problem. Also, try to understand why it is a problem. (you could also install the shellcheck program on your system)

**note on math:** your solutions for `x1` and `x2` are wrong. The notation `$((-b/2*a+calc/2*a))` actually multiplies with `a` and does not *divide*. So it should read `$(( (-b+calc)/(2*a) ))` and `$(( (-b-calc)/(2*a) ))`

**note on bash:** Bash has no knowledge of floating-point arithmetic.

> **ARITHMETIC EVALUATION:** The shell allows arithmetic expressions to be evaluated, under certain circumstances (see the let and declare
>          builtin commands and Arithmetic Expansion).  Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow, though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error.
>
> **source: `man bash`**

This implies that a bash solution can only work if and only if the input is extremely well designed and must satisfy the following conditions:

1. The discriminant `d` is a perfect square. So it needs to have any of the following values: `1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 ... n^2`
2. From the solutions of `x1` and `x2` we know that `b` must be divisible by `2*a` and the same holds for `calc` and thus, `d` must be divisible by `4*a*a`.

There are only a handful of infinite combinations possible that satisfy this condition.

If you want your solution to be pure bash, it also implies that you cannot make use of any other tools such as `bc` or `awk` or `python` or `perl`. A detailed list of such workarounds with such tools can be found here: [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks), but unfortunately you cannot make use of this. But this makes life a bit difficult.

To this end, I would suggest making use of `bc -l` for all your math computations.

- `d=$( bc - l <<< "$b*$b - 4.0*$a*$c" )`
- `calc=$( bc - l <<< "sqrt($d)" )`
- `x1=$( bc -l <<< "(-$b+$calc)/(2.0*$a)" )`

To avoid the usage of `echo`, we make use of a `HERESTRING` (see `man bash`)

You could check if `d` is bigger then zero, by testing with a regex if `d` contains a hyphen (`-`) (search for `=~` in `man bash`)

But this would still be cheating as you make use of `bc`. Pure bash is difficult. The only way I can see doing it is by multiplying all your numbers with a large number and then divide afterwards again. (This could all be done simply by using string manipulation. Example if the input is `2` convert it to `200000000`, if the input is `-2.5` convert it to `-250000000` (as if you multiplied with 100000000). The `sqrt` could be done with a lookup table or a simple binary search.

Comment: so how do you thhink i should type the x1,x2 lines? what is a correct way?

Comment: @FilipposPapalos if you can use `bc` then you can use `awk` as they're both standard UNIX tools as included in SUS and then your life becomes a whole lot easier. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unix_commands.

Answer (score 0):

for few changes using zsh instead of bash  note `-l` option

```
calc=$(echo "sqrt ($d)" | bc -l)
```